SSMS: Is there a faster way to SELECT TOP (1000) in the GUI?
Today, I'm checking every table in a massive database and writing a summary of what each is. This means that I'm right-clicking and pressing "Select Top 1000 Rows" a great many times. Is there a faster way? I'd prefer one tab per table, so SQL tricks are probably out. What I want to do is increase the speed that I'm navigating SSMS.

The only way that I can think of to help you with this would be to pre-generate all the SELECT statements, then you can run groups of them at once.
I have other thoughts about using a notebook in Azure Data Studio and manually editing it's contents, but for a one-time operation that seems like a lot of work.  Also a possibility is something like Autoscript or maybe PowerShell to programmatically do that task for you.
But what I would do if I faced your task would be to use this to pre-generate the list of SELECTs for me, then copy/paste the SQLCMD results into a new tab and then just go down the list, maybe a few at a time, executing them, reviewing the contents and then moving along.
SELECT S.name AS SchemaName
    , T.name AS TableName
    , SQLCMD = N'SELECT TOP (1000) * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(S.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(T.name)
FROM sys.tables AS T
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS S ON S.schema_id = T.schema_id
WHERE T.is_ms_shipped = 0 /** ignore integrated system tables **/
ORDER BY S.name, T.name

